# Validation rule bypasses null value

Tags: validation

I have two percent fields in this validation rule

> Day_Split__c + Night_Split__c < 1

Works well when both values are entered. However, if one of them is *null*, the validation rule evaluates to true.

Is there a formula or workaround without writing bunch of IF statements? Formula abs() did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Found formula [nullvalue()](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#NULLVALUE). The validation that worked is

```
nullvalue(Day_Split__c,0) + nullvalue(Night_Split__c, 0) < 1
```

Comment: On the link you provided there is a note on using BlankValue over NullValue, Use BLANKVALUE instead of NULLVALUE in new formulas. BLANKVALUE has the same functionality as NULLVALUE, but also supports text fields. Salesforce will continue to support NULLVALUE, so you do not need to change existing formulas.